# What information do I need to connect a domain?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, domain-registration, godaddy

I need to connect my domain to my site. What information do I need to have from my domain host to connect it to my site that is hosted. I am using a webhost that uses cpanel if this helps, in this case godaddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What information do I need to have from my domain host

"domain host" is really called the *domain registrar* - the organisation through which the domain is registered.

You need to set the NAMESERVERS at your domain registrar to point to your webhost. Your webhost will be able to tell you what the required NAMESERVERS are. There should be at least two.

Once you have set the NAMESERVERS it can take some time (up to 48 hours) for the DNS to propagate. Before everyone can reliably type in your domain name to get to your site.

Note that you must also set your domain name at your webhost, otherwise your host will not accept the requests.

Once the NAMESERVERS are pointing at your webhost then any DNS changes are made at your webhost, not your domain registrar. Your webhost now holds the master DNS records. Since you are using cPanel this is beneficial.